# DetailView for Django Formset

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, formset

I'm using Django inlineformsets for the first time and I'm trying to work on my views. I've been able to create my Create and Update views but I'm lost on how to go about the Detail View. I basically have 2 models - SchoolMain and SchoolSub with SchoolSub having a fk relationship with SchoolMain. SchoolSub is my formset. My Create View is below -

```
class SchoolSubCreate(LoginRequiredMixin,UserPassesTestMixin,generic.CreateView):
    model = SchoolMain
    fields = '__all__'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(SchoolSubCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['schoolsub'] = SchoolSubFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            data['schoolsub'] = SchoolSubFormSet()

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        schoolsub = context['schoolsub']
        with transaction.atomic():
            form.instance.user = self.request.user
            self.object = form.save()

            if schoolsub.is_valid():
                schoolsub.instance = self.object
                schoolsub.save()
        return super(SchoolSubCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

I understand how to go about creating a general DetailView, but that is only able to get the object of my primary model i.e. the SchoolMain model. But I'm unable to access the objects in the formset. Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to edit the formset in the detail view ?

Comment: Nope, I want to be able to view the information uploaded in the CreateView as a detailed profile in my DetailView

Comment: you have to only call it using reverse relation. school_main_object.schoolsub_set.all()  will give you the SchoolSub objects.

Comment: Great, that worked. Also, how would you loop through the fields to show all of them in the template? thanks.

Comment: Figured it out. thanks a ton!